# Safari not playing video in quicktime plugin over https or basic auth

Tags: safari, html5-video, quicktime

I'm trying to load a video with a standard html5 video tag.  This works fine in all browsers except safari.  When I load this in safari (both desktop and iOS), The video plays fine over http.  If I switch to https or use basic auth, the video won't load.

I'm pretty sure the issue is that the quicktime plugin is can't access the cookies that safari has. So it doesn't recognize the authentication.  Has anyone come across this and what can I do about it?

Comment: Can you upload a demo somewhere? Did you check the error console?

Comment: You can download a zip file of an example using basic auth here http://www.fileswap.com/dl/zRn4J9ofuQ/.  Just drop it in your apache Documents folder.  Change the password file path in htaccess to match your environment.  The username is btate the password is test.  I have two videos side by side.  One is calling an external video over http.  One is hitting a video in the same folder which is behind basic auth.